# Understanding positive and negative lookaheads

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to understand how negative lookaheads work on simple examples. For instance, consider the following regex:

```regex
a(?!b)c
```

I thought the negative lookahead matches a position. So, in that case the regex matches any string that contains strictly 3 characters and is not `abc`.

But it's not true, as can be seen in **[this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM4tF1/4)**. Why?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, it's helpful, but it was the first result in the google :) I've read it

Comment: To add to this problem, a common misconception is that you can use negative lookaheads to substitute for multi-word negation or even attempt otherwise, so you will see broken regexes like these: `[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z])`, `[^sword]fish`, `(?!sword)fish`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Lookaheads do not consume any characters. It just checks if the lookahead can be matched or not:

```
a(?!b)c
```

So here after matching `a` it just *checks* if it is followed not by `b` but does not consume that `not` character (which is `c`) and is followed by `c`.

### How `a(?!b)c` matches `ac`

```
ac
|
a

ac
 |
(?!b) #checks but does not consume. Pointer remains at c

ac
 |
 c
```

---

### Positive lookahead

The positive lookahead is similar in that it ***tries to match the pattern in the lookahead***. If it can be matched, then the regex engine proceeds with matching the rest of the pattern. If it cannot, the match is discarded.

E.g.

`abc(?=123)\d+` matching  `abc123`

```
abc123
|
a

abc123
 |
 b

abc123
  c

abc123 #Tries to match 123; since is successful, the pointer remains at c
    |
 (?=123)

abc123 # Match is success. Further matching of patterns (if any) would proceed from this position
  |

abc123
   |
  \d

abc123
    |
   \d

abc123 #Reaches the end of input. The pattern is matched completely. Returns a successfull match by the regex engine
     |
    \d
```

Comment: Important to note maybe that in, for example, `.+(?!b).+` if `(?!b)` fails, the first `.+` will try match a shorter string, and then the check is done again. As such, `.+(?!b).+` would match `bbbabb` with the first `.+` matching `bbb` and the second one matching `abb`. ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE8rM0/1))

Comment: Rather than say that backtracking occurs, it's probably more correct to say that the pointer never moves. Backtracking happens with regular matching when the pattern fails.

Comment: Couldn't you make a note about positive lookahead? Is that the same as the negative lookahead unless it checks that the pattern in `(?=pattern)` _is_ matched.

Comment: @St.Antario Yup. It just checks if the pattern can be matched. if it can be matched it will proceed with the rest pattern else will discard. Take a look at [this answer which i just answered on look ahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701747/regular-expression-which-allows-numbers-spaces-plus-sign-hyphen-and-brackets)

Comment: @St.Antario I have added an edit on postive look ahead as well. Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 8):

@Antario, I was confused about the negative look ahead/behind case in regex for a while and [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html) site has a great explanation.

So with your example what you are saying is that you have a literal "a" and it is NOT followed by a literal "b" and it IS followed by a literal "c".

Here is a different regex debugger than you used which gives a more visual answer which personally I find helpful :)

`a(?!b)c`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xRPFXTtZtg2dUR-X)

Answer (score 3):

`a(?!b)c` will match only `ac` because the only way you'll have an `a` followed by "not `b`" (which will not be consumed) and then `c`, is `ac`.

Answer (score 2):

> > So, in that case the regex matches any string that contains strictly 3 characters and is not the abc

This is not quite right. This regex states that we are searching a sequence which firstsymbol is `a` and after that is `c`, and inside there is no `b`.

For example, `a(?!b).` will match either `ac` or `af` as there is no restrictions on the last symbol via `.`

Comment: There's no condition that the string start with `a` or end with `c`. Only that it contain `ac`