# Regular expression which allows numbers, spaces, plus sign, hyphen and brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery validator where I have added a method to validate a string which allow only numbers, spaces, plus sign, hyphen and brackets. Number is mandatory in the string but other charterer is optional.

My code for adding method in jquery validor:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod( "regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);
```

Following code for the rules:

```
rules: {
myfield: {
    required: true,
    regex: "[0-9]+" // want to add regular expression but I wrote only for digit which works but do not understand how to reach at my requirements.
 },
}
```

Comment: Use a regular expression tester program to help you play around with and test various inputs: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: A simple search for "regular expression syntax" should provide you with the knowledge needed to intelligently craft and debug.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can add the required characters into character class as

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])[- +()0-9]+$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zM1hP9/2)

**Regex Explanation**

- `(?=.*[0-9])` postive look ahead. Ensures that there is atleast one digit
- `[- +()0-9]+` matches numbers, spaces, plus sign, hyphen and brackets

**OR**

If you are reluctant in using look aheads. You could write without them a lenghier regex as

```
/^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$/
```

Comment: Without lookahead: `/^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*/`

Comment: Great Thanks, "/^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$/" it solve my issue.

Comment: I'm using your REGEX, in my angular 2 app in pattern as `<input class="input-minimal" pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])[- +()0-9]+$" [(ngModel)]="staff.mobile" name="staffMobile" formControlName="mobile"  required type="text">`
`<span class="error-msg" *ngIf="!addStaffForm.controls['mobile'].valid && (addStaffForm.controls['mobile'].touched || isFormSubmited)" translate>Please enter a valid mobile number</span>`  But it doesn't work for numbers like (808)8997646. Please help

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.