# Simple phone number regex to match numbers, spaces, etc

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to modify a fairly basic regex pattern in C# that tests for phone numbers.

The patterns is -

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

I have two questions -

1) The existing expression does work (although it is fairly restrictive) but I can't quite understand how it works. Regexps for similar issues seem to look more like this one -

```
/^[0-9()]+$/
```

2) How could I extend this pattern to allow brackets, periods and a single space to separate numbers. I tried a few variations to include -

```
[0-9().+\s?](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

Although i can't seem to create a valid pattern.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at this answer. It may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701747/regular-expression-which-allows-numbers-spaces-plus-sign-hyphen-and-brackets

Comment: Explore your pattern at http://www.regex101.com

Comment: Your requirement for brackets to separate number does not make sense to me.  Please show us some data.

Comment: Hi Tim, it's probably just an error in the way I've provided the regexps above but an example phone number could be - +44 (0)20 2836 5018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

First of all, I recommend checking out either regexr.com or regex101.com, so you yourself get an understanding of how regex works. Both websites will give you a step-by-step explanation of what each symbol in the regex does.

Now, one of the main things you have to understand is that regex has *special characters*. This includes, among others, the following: `[]().-+*?\^$`. So, if you want your regex to match a literal `.`, for example, you would have to escape it, since it's a special character. To do so, either use `\.` or `[.]`. Backslashes serve to escape other characters, while `[]` means "match any one of the characters in this set". Some special characters don't have a special meaning inside these brackets and don't require escaping.

Therefore, the regex above will match any combination of digits of length 1 or more, followed by an optional suffix `(foobar)?`, which has to be a dot, followed by one or two digits. In fact, this regex seems more like it's supposed to match decimal numbers with up to two digits behind the dot - not phone numbers.

```
/^[0-9()]+$/
```

What this does is pretty simple - match any combination of digits or round brackets that has the length 1 or greater.

```
[0-9().+\s?](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

What you're matching here is:

- one of: a digit, round bracket, dot, plus sign, whitespace or question mark; but **exactly once** only!
- optionally followed by a dot and one or two digits

A suitable regex for your purpose could be:

```
(\+\d{2})?((\(0\)\d{2,3})|\d{2,3})?\d+
```

Enter this in one of the websites mentioned above to understand how it works. I modified it a little to also allow, for example +49 123 4567890.
Also, for simplicity, I didn't include spaces - so when using this regex, you have to remove all the spaces in your input first. In C#, that should be possible with `yourString.Replace(" ", "");` (simply replacing all spaces with nothing = deleting spaces)

Comment: Thanks very much (and thanks everyone else for answers too). This was really useful and led me to find the right expression for my site.

The completed version is -

    (\+{0,1}|\({0,1}(([\d]+)\-{0,1}\){0,1}\s{0,1}))+

which allows me to test for a number which either starts with '+' or a '('

followed by a sequence of numbers.

the sequence of numbers can either be separated by a space or a '-' or a ')'.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` after the character set is a quantifier (meaning the preceeding character, character set or group is repeated) at least one, and unlimited number of times and it's greedy (matched the most possible).

Then `[0-9().+\s]+` will match any character in set one or more times.