# Finding specific terms with regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

i am extracting text from a pdf and i want to search for an expression like **P50+P60**, but in the text there are also terms like **P50+P40+P30**.
How can i implement, that i just find a Structure like **Pxx+Pxx** (x=digit) and there is nothing found for **Pxx+Pxx+Pxx**.

I tried it like this

**List = re.findall('(P\d\d+P\d\d[^\+P\d\d])', String)**

but this shows also the **P50+P40** from the term **P50+P40+P30**.
I tried a lot but couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: As per the documentation, you could use [negative lookahead assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Understanding negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691225/understanding-negative-lookahead), negative lookahead alone would not help, `P\d\d+` needed excluding, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'(?<!P\d\d\+)P\d\d\+P\d\d(?!\+P\d\d)', String)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/r8inDL/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    P                        'P'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  P                        'P'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  P                        'P'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    P                        'P'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```