# Regex that doesn't contain is|has prefix but ends with : Bool

Tags: regex, swiftlint

Sorry that I have to ask that, with all the other answers around, but I can't get my head around to think and adapt to my problem.

So I'm writing a custom SwiftLint rule that should check:

- does **not** have `is` or `has` prefix
- does have `: Bool` suffix

My current Regex looks like this, but it shows me the stuff that contains is or has, but I want it to show me things that don't have it

```
(is|has)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(: Bool)
```

I also tried this, but it won't show me any message, so I guess it's wrong:

```
^(?!is|has)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*: Bool$
```

So, what's the correct Regex?

---

EDIT:
How it should be:

```
`isHello: Bool` -> nothing
hello: Bool -> should alarm me, missing is or has prefix
```

---

EDIT 2:

```
@State private var showActionSheet: Bool = false -> should give me a warning
@State private var hasStartWorkout: Bool = false -> should not give me a warning
```

Comment: is the is/has the start of the line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding positive and negative lookaheads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691225/understanding-positive-and-negative-lookaheads)

Comment: why do you require capital at start of your regex but your sample is lowercase?

Comment: @jhnc I actually dont know, but you are right, thats an error from my side

Comment: one ugly way is you can write ([^ih]|i[^s]|h[^a]|ha[^s]) to match some character that aren't is or has

Comment: since you appear not to actually want to match at start/end of line, nor to require uppercase, perhaps: `\b(?!is|has)[A-Za-z]+: Bool\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that in a successful case of the negative lookahead the following regex part is not matching: "^(?!is|has)**[A-Z]**[A-Za-z]*: Bool$". In your example, the line that doesn't start with is/has ("hello") starts with a lower character. So you have to move said part inside of the negative lookahead like in this regex:

```
(^| )(?!has[A-Z]|is[A-Z])[A-Za-z]+: Bool
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the problem persists. Sadly, I still get errors, even if it has the is or has as a prefix.

Comment: Can you give me some example lines which are wrongly matched / not matched?

Comment: I updated my question with an edit at the bottom, both get flagged tho

Comment: I updated my solution. If you encounter further cases my regex handles incorrectly, please update your question with the corresponding lines

Comment: It works if you change (or eliminate) the anchoring (^$). I see it’s been fixed. <thumbs up>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need something rather ugly like this:

`/^([^ih]|i[^s]|h[^a]|ha[^s])[A-Za-z]*: Bool$/gm`

And it gets even uglier if you need to enforce an uppercase after the “is” or “has”.

That’s only if you need pure regex. If you can use something like `grep -v`, life is simpler…

Updated for your “Edit 2”:
`/( |^)([^ih]|i[^s]|h[^a]|ha[^s])[A-Za-z]*: Bool/gm`